# Python: Return tuple value to function and calling a specfic value. TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, yolov5

Hello this is my first Post ever so if I can do anything to improve please tell me.

So I am returning to variables x, y to a function.

When I output the Tuple value in my main function with print(`coords()`) it works perfectly fine.
It just returns 2 int values (500, 400).
When I try `print(coords()[0])` I should get my X value, but I do get a:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The best part is it worked yesterday just like that, when I reopened my Project today it just doesn't work anymore.

Running this code without any functions works perfectly fine as well.

Also interesting is that sometimes trying `print(coords()[0])` works for a second and shows the right results, but then crashes with Type Error.

I am using Yolov5, but Yolo is working perfectly fine, and it's only trying to get the coordinates of a **single object**.

```py
def coords():
rl = detection.xyxy[0].tolist()

        #calculates x and y pos from detected bonding box pixel location
        if len(rl) > 0:
            if rl[0][4] > 0.7:
                if rl[0][5] == 0:             
                    width = float(rl[0][2]) - float(rl[0][0])
                    height = float(rl[0][3]) - float(rl[0][1])

                    x = float(rl[0][2]) - (width / 2)
                    y = float(rl[0][3]) - (height / 2) + 15

                    return int(x), int(y)

                    #yesterday my code looked like this
                    #coords = x, y
                    #return list(coords) # but this results in the same type error
                    
def main():
    while True:
       print(coords()) # does work
       print(coords()[0]) # does not work , but did yesterday
```

Comment: If any of the top three `if` conditions are false, the function will never make it to the `return int(x), int(y)` line, and ends up returning None by default.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I also tried adding else: None but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "I also tried adding else: None".  That code, by itself, does not **return** anything, so what purpose does it serve?

Comment: No you are right Im stupid, I filtered the None values and now it does work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from John Gordon is right:
If any of the top three if conditions are false, the function will never make it to the return int(x), int(y) line, and ends up returning None by default.

I filtered the None Values now it's working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).